# Deploying Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using `MacOS`.

I used following command:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy start --runtime python37
  --trigger-http --memory 2048MB --timeout 540s
```

But while deploying `google cloud functions` I got this error:

```
(gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: USER ERROR:
pip_download_wheels had stderr output:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wheel-8b_hn74q/PyWavelets/
error: pip_download_wheels returned code: 1
```

I added `scikit-image` in my `requirements.txt`, which was not added before. Code was successfully deploying when `scikit-image` was not added in `requirements.txt`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you followed the [previous steps](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart#before-you-begin) in order to deploy the Cloud Functions as well as the Mac OS X [Python installing instructions](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#mac_os_x)?

Comment: Yes, I did follow all the instructions carefully.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. Did you find a fix? Cloud Functions might only work for pure-python code, so dependencies that required compilation like scikit don't work?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a Pipfile in your directory? I was able to replicate this same error when I tried to deploy a GCF containing a Pipfile but no accompanying Pipfile.lock. To fix, either remove Pipfile and just include requirements.txt, or generate Pipfile.lock:

`$ pipenv install` without the --skip-lock flag

While the current documentation does not state this, I have found that you can deploy to GCF without a requirements.txt file at all. Just include Pipfile and Pipfile.lock.

To recap, acceptable dependency files to deploy a beta GCF:

- requirements.txt
- Pipfile + Pipfile.lock
- requirements.txt + Pipfile + Pipfile.lock

Comment: I have neither "pipfile" nor "pipfile.lock" files in my directory .I have only used "requirements.txt" in my directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to the google cloud function [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies) it only supports installing dependency from `requirements.txt` file.

And the file `Pipfile/Pipfile.lock` must not be present in the root directory.